# ant sync task deletes the directory mentioned to preserve

Tags: ant, preserve

I want to preserve the ".git" directory with all of it's content while executing synk ant task, but it deletes the content of .git directory.

```
<sync todir="${local.git.dir}" includeEmptyDirs="true">
    <fileset dir="${img.dir}"/>
    <preserveintarget>
        <include name=".git"/>
    </preserveintarget>
</sync>
```

Why according to this syntax, synk deletes the content of the .git directory?

This synk task should copy the file f1 (`dir="${img.dir}"`) into the directory dir1 (`todir="${local.git.dir}"`); dir1 contains the directory .git.

Synk task doesn't delete the content of the .git directory only if I mention to put the file f1 into the directory dir1/target. In this case I will have this structure:

- dir1 contains the directories: .git and target
- the file f1 is copied into the target directory (which I don't want)

I want dir1 to contain .git and f1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I didn't specified to preserve the files in the .git.

By appending /** to .git I resolved the problem: `<include name=".git/**"/>` instead of `<include name=".git"/>`